# Clicking the Tabs' button doesn't show the components

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-tabs

There is a `Tabs` component which has two tab :

```
private Tabs tabClient = new Tabs();
...
tabClient.addTab("Fiche", cFicheClient); // cFicheClient is a Container
tabClient.addTab("Crédits", cClientEtCredits); // cClientEtCredits is a Container
tabClient.addTabsFocusListener(this);

public void focusGained(Component arg0) {
        String noms = Formatage.getColumnValueAt(String.valueOf(fichesignalitique.elementAt(0)).toUpperCase(), 11);
        if (tabClient.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
            setTitle("Fiche signalétique de " + noms);
            photosBtn.requestFocus();
        }
        else
        {
            setTitle("Liste des crédits de " + noms);
            recapClient.requestFocus();
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

In runtime I cannot click the "Crédits" tab : the Tabs doesn't show the components of the `cClientEtCredits` Container ! And also the `Form`'s title is not displayed when the `Form` is shown but I must click one tab button in order to show the `Form`'s title !

So why ?

Comment: This is just a snippet, need to provide more code to analyze the reason for container `cClientEtCredits` not being shown. Also need relevant code for form title container manipulation in the your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing its because of the request focus call within a focus listener.

You should probably change the tab selection **before** moving the focus to a different component by using something like `setSelectedIndex`.